# Whitespace below CoordinatorLayout in DrawerLayout

Tags: android, android-support-library, material-design, android-support-design

I am trying to implement a layout with a `CollapsingToolbarLayout` inside a `DrawerLayout`. The whole `acitivty_main.xml` looks like this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main__drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- The CoordinatorLayout is used to coordinate (rly) scroll events between different views -->
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!-- The AppBar (everything above the scrolling content) -->
        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/activity_main__app_bar"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/activity_main__collapsing_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/appbar_size_expanded"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="16dp"
                app:expandedTitleMarginStart="72dp"
                app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="32dp"
                app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/ExpandedAppBarTitle"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/activity_main__toolbar"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <!-- The scrolling content view -->
        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/activity_main__content_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#CCC333"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

        <!-- The add button -->
        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/activity_main__floating_action_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            app:layout_anchor="@+id/activity_main__app_bar"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
            app:borderWidth="0dp"
            app:elevation="@dimen/fab_elevation" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/activity_main__navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_navigation_header" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The layout and app structure is loosely based on [this tutorial by codepath](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Fragment-Navigation-Drawer), where I have changed the `FrameLayout` for a `NestedScrollView` (even though the effect appears with both).

Now the view I intend to use for the actual content has some weird padding (I have used a background color to clarify where it is actually rendered):

[image: device capture]

Where did I mess up?

Comment: Have you got a solution for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Where did I mess up?

It's Design Library's fault. Layouts "shorter" than screen height cause gaps, misbehaviour in collapsing/unfolding `<CollapsingToolbarLayout>` (i.e. you need to drag *outside* of collapsed area to unfold it again etc, etc, etc. It's just quite buggy at the moment or writing this answer (it will, hopefully be fixed some day, but I got no clue when this is going to happen).

Comment: Is there any suggested workaround maybe? My sublayout is a `LinearLayout` with `layout_height="match_parent"`  and inside it a `TextView` with the same, I don't get how it's shorter than screen height.

Comment: @Marcin Orlowski: Any updates on this? It's 2018 and still facing this issue.

Comment: I agree with your answer but how whatsApp do it?

Comment: No idea, but you can always write your own version of this component, which is most likely what they did.

Answer (score -1):

Try to remove the : exitUntilCollapsed

Into CollapsingToolbarlayout you have now this code

```
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"
```