# How to remove empty white space at the bottom of CoordinatorLayout with NestedScrollView

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout, nestedscrollview

I am working with `CoordinatorLayout` in which i am using `AppbarLayout` along with `ViewPager`, `Nestedscrollview` and `TabLayout`. On scroll of layout `AppbarLayout` folds and unfolds.

Now the issue is that onscroll of this layout it leaves empty white space at bottom which I don't want.

**Here is my Drawer-Layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/coordinator"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="220dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/offer_image"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
                    <!--    <com.flaviofaria.kenburnsview.KenBurnsView
                            android:id="@+id/image"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="220dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/offer_image" />-->
                    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
                        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
                        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">


                        <com.flaviofaria.kenburnsview.KenBurnsView
                            android:id="@+id/image"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="220dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/offer_image" />

                        <FrameLayout
                            android:id="@+id/collapse_frame"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:background="#B3c85a00">

                        </FrameLayout>

                        <FrameLayout
                            android:id="@+id/centerCircle"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center">

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/imageViewCenter"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center" />
                        </FrameLayout>


                        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                            android:id="@+id/tabs"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                            app:tabIndicatorColor="#FFFFFF"
                            app:tabMode="scrollable" />
                        <!--</FrameLayout>-->
                    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
                </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

                <!--<FrameLayout-->

                <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
                <!--android:layout_height="match_parent"-->
                <!-- -->
                <!--android:visibility="visible">-->

                <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                    android:id="@+id/fab"
                    style="@style/floating_action_button"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_share_white_24dp"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    app:backgroundTint="#FF9800"
                    app:elevation="6dp"
                    app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp" />

                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager

                    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:id="@+id/pager_pre"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="left|bottom|fill_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

                </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>


            </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/bannerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="58dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
                android:background="@drawable/curved_white_with_blue_border"
                android:visibility="gone">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/bannerText"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="3dp"
                    android:text="Banner"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/bannerImage"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="3dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/bannerClose"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/cross_icon" />
            </RelativeLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/socialTabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="46dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:background="@color/White"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:visibility="gone">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/follow" />

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="@color/White">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="46dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                        android:paddingRight="10dp"
                        android:weightSum="3">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/facebookImageView"
                            android:layout_width="30dp"
                            android:layout_height="30dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:src="@drawable/fb_follow" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/googlePlusImageView"
                            android:layout_width="30dp"
                            android:layout_height="30dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                            android:src="@drawable/google_follow" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/twitterImageView"
                            android:layout_width="30dp"
                            android:layout_height="30dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                            android:src="@drawable/twitter_follow" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </FrameLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:id="@+id/snackbarCoordinatorLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="265dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:groupIndicator="@null"
        android:scrollbars="@null" />
    <!--    <FrameLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame"></FrameLayout>-->

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**NestedScrollView's code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/fragment_back_color"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="5dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="@drawable/new_recharge" />

                <com.spiceladdoo.views.RobotTextviewRegular
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:text="NEW PAYMENT"
                    android:textColor="@color/offer_name_text_color" />

            </LinearLayout>


            <RelativeLayout

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="20dp">

                <HorizontalScrollView
                    android:id="@+id/hsv"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:fillViewport="true"
                    android:measureAllChildren="false"
                    android:scrollbars="none">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/wallet_layout"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/wallet_recharge"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:background="@drawable/wallet_recherge" />

                            <com.spiceladdoo.views.RobotTextviewRegular
                                android:layout_width="65dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:text="WALLET"
                                android:textColor="@color/offer_name_text_color"
                                android:textSize="12sp" />

                        </LinearLayout>

                        <View
                            android:layout_width="5dp"
                            android:layout_height="20dp"

                            android:background="@color/white" />

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/prepaid_layout"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/prepaid_recharge"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:background="@drawable/prepaid_recherge" />

                            <com.spiceladdoo.views.RobotTextviewRegular
                                android:layout_width="65dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:text="PREPAID"
                                android:textColor="@color/offer_name_text_color"
                                android:textSize="12sp" />


                        </LinearLayout>

                        <View
                            android:layout_width="5dp"
                            android:layout_height="20dp"

                            android:background="@color/white" />

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/postpaid_layout"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/postpaid_recharge"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:background="@drawable/postpaid_recherge" />

                            <com.spiceladdoo.views.RobotTextviewRegular
                                android:layout_width="65dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:text="POSTPAID"
                                android:textColor="@color/offer_name_text_color"
                                android:textSize="12sp" />


                        </LinearLayout>

                        <View
                            android:layout_width="5dp"
                            android:layout_height="20dp"
                            android:background="@color/white" />

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/dth_layout"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/dth_recharge"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:background="@drawable/dth_recherge" />

                            <com.spiceladdoo.views.RobotTextviewRegular
                                android:layout_width="65dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:text="DTH"
                                android:textColor="@color/offer_name_text_color"
                                android:textSize="12sp" />


                        </LinearLayout>

                        <View
                            android:layout_width="5dp"
                            android:layout_height="20dp"
                            android:background="@color/white" />

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/landline_layout"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/landline_recharge"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:background="@drawable/landline_recherge" />

                            <com.spiceladdoo.views.RobotTextviewRegular
                                android:layout_width="65dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:text="LANDLINE"
                                android:textColor="@color/offer_name_text_color"
                                android:textSize="12sp" />


                        </LinearLayout>

                        <View
                            android:layout_width="5dp"
                            android:layout_height="20dp"
                            android:background="@color/white" />

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/datacard_layout"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/datacard_recharge"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:background="@drawable/datacard_recherge" />

                            <com.spiceladdoo.views.RobotTextviewRegular
                                android:layout_width="65dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:text="DATACARD"
                                android:textColor="@color/offer_name_text_color"
                                android:textSize="12sp" />
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </HorizontalScrollView>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center" />

                <com.spiceladdoo.views.RobotTextviewRegular
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:text="RECENT"
                    android:textColor="@color/offer_name_text_color" />

            </LinearLayout>


            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/lincontainer_rec"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
                    android:divider="?android:dividerHorizontal"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                    android:paddingRight="16dp"
                    android:showDividers="middle" />
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

I am sharing a video click of this problem:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/9yojeq2yw1eebps/layout_height_issue.mp4?dl=0

I am banging my head on this from last three days.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I was looking for this link, so i found it finally, take a look : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31266078/whitespace-below-coordinatorlayout-in-drawerlayout

Comment: @Martijn Pieters This is not a off-topic in my knowledge. This seems OK to me.. please open it

Comment: @Kool: this post was auto-flagged for length. It is *huge*. I'm sure the posted XML can be reduced to a minimal example, rather than just a code dump.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I understand but here need to post everything to make question more clear.. every views property is dependent on other.. you should reopen it again

Comment: @TGMCians: however you keep questions useful for future visitors with these kind of code dumps is beyond me. Reopened.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks :)

Comment: @TGMCians I agree with Martijn, the XML is so lengthy cant even debug it by just looking!

Answer (score 4):

**Try to add :**

```
android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
```

To the `NestedScrollView` and `RecyclerView`.(or you can try it just for `NestedScrollView`).

Also, check this link too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31266160/4409113

Which said:

> It's Design Library's fault. Layouts "shorter" than screen height
>   cause gaps, misbehaviour in collapsing/unfolding
>    (i.e. you need to drag outside of collapsed
>   area to unfold it again etc, etc, etc. It's just quite buggy at the
>   moment or writing this answer (it will, hopefully be fixed some day,
>   but I got no clue when this is going to happen).

By the way, I am using the following codes and it's working with `match_parent`:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cvuser"
            android:layout_width="365dp"
            android:layout_height="140dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
            card_view:cardElevation="1dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/idrel"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="140dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtmessage"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginStart="17dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtauthor"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/txtmessage"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="35dp"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />


            </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

And i saw the video again and the thing is your contents are not enough for Scrolling.I mean, if you can add the above `CardView` with a `RecyclerView`, you'll see what will happens.the contents are not enough for scrolling and more contents into the `NestedScrollView` and then with match_parent, it should work.

Comment: Try to add it with java sometimes java will do the same exactly.if it didn't work, sounds like a fault or something like that from support library.or if it wasn't, you may want to wait for an answer from google staffs.that should be interesting...

Comment: But some apps are doing it so pretty. One of them is  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.snapdeal.main&hl=en