# Extra blank space on CoordinatorLayout with a ScrollView and ListView

Tags: android, android-studio, android-scrollview, android-coordinatorlayout, nestedscrollview

I've created a Scrolling Activity using the Android Studio template, this created an activity.xml and also a content.xml which is included on the activity.xml who has a NestedScrollView into which I've added a ListView feed from an adapter, at first it only showed one item so I programmatically made the size of it to a fixed value so that it actually shows all the items, I was able to do that without a problem and the NestedScrollView wraps the ListView with no problem, however there is a blank space below the NestedScrollView that I realize was from the CoordinatorLayout by adding background colors to all elements, the CoordinatorLayout is the main tag in the activity.xml but I am not able to figure out how to remove this blank space since if I use wrap_content on the CoordinatorLayout it will actually trim my content to half the screen for some reason.

The other things that are worth to mention are that this blanks space is not showing if I rotate my phone horizontally, is only coming up on a vertical position. Also,

Does anyone know what might be causing this? Is not a big deal and I might even end up leaving it like this but it's just annoying to me I'm not able to figure out what's going on.

This is my activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="#00ff00" //Green
    tools:context=".VenueActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:src="@drawable/frog"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_venue"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_favorite_white_24dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This is my content.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".VenueActivity"
    android:background="#ff0000" //Blue
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_venue">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/venueList"
        android:background="#ffff00" //Yellow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <SearchView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:id="@+id/searchView"
            android:queryHint="Search venues">

        </SearchView>

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/songList" />

    </LinearLayout>


</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Finally my java file:

```
package com.example.android.myApplication;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class VenueActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //Set up my own database manually
    String[] db_ids = {"12345", "12345", "12345", "12345", "12345", "12345"};
    String[] db_songs = {"Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5", "Item 6"};
    int[] db_thumbs = {R.drawable.ic_place_white_24dp, R.drawable.ic_place_white_24dp,
            R.drawable.ic_place_white_24dp, R.drawable.ic_place_white_24dp,
            R.drawable.ic_place_white_24dp, R.drawable.ic_place_white_24dp};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_venue);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        Toast.makeText(VenueActivity.this, getIntent().getStringExtra("venue") + " was choosen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Venue has been added to your favourites", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        /**
         *  LISTVIEW TO DISPLAY DIFFRENT VENUES
         */

        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.songList);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                TextView selectedSong = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.songName);
                // TODO Third Fragment must be changed to the Venue Home or something different than this
                Toast.makeText(VenueActivity.this, selectedSong.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //     Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(),VenueActivity.class);
                //    intent.putExtra("venue", selectedVenue.getText());
                //     startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        SongArrayAdapter ad = new SongArrayAdapter(db_ids, db_songs, db_thumbs, getApplicationContext());
        lv.setAdapter(ad);
        ListViewInScrollView.adapt(lv);

    }
}
```

[image: Vertical View scrolled all the way to the bottom]

[image: Horizontal View scrolled all the way to the bottom]

Comment: android:fillViewport="true" for NestedScrollView

Comment: Hi @keshav, actually my NestedScrollView has the correct size, the green area is actually part of the CoordinatorLayout, i know this because if I use match_parent in the NestedScrollView the green becomes blue which is the background color of my NestedScrollView.

Comment: Check my previously answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/41372551/3614180 Try to remove into CollapsingToolbarLayout the value 'exitUntilCollapsed'

Comment: Any solution @Balibrera?

Comment: I've ended up in using ScrollView not Nested one.

Comment: @Balibrera u got any solution for this?